# Google Earth Engine Tile error: Array arguments must have same length along one axis

Tags: javascript, image, google-earth-engine

I am trying to run some code to export a gee image. Everything is fine except the final part, when exporting the image it gives me:

> Tile error: Array arguments must have same length along one axis.

```
var image1 = ee.Image(...); 
print(image1);
```

So far, so good, but then:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image1.clip(roi),
  description: 'image1',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 10,
  folder: 'Modelo v2',
  region: roi
});
//"Tile error: Array arguments must have same length along one axis."
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please note the guidance/descriptions given when you choose a tag. The [[tag:gee]] tag is used for a specific library, not for Google Earth Engine. (Note: I've since renamed it to [[tag:libgee]] to hopefully avoid any future confusion.)